# GLEW linker errors undefined reference to '_glew*'

Tags: c++, windows, linker, glew, mingw-w64

I am trying to compile a [game](https://github.com/endless-sky/endless-sky) that I don't made but it is failing due to LOTS and LOTS of errors that are "undefined reference to __glewSomething"

The project by default links against the dll version of glew, that gives those errors, when I link against the static version, I get a different set of errors.

The second set of errors, is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475234/undefined-references-to-imp-glew-functions-with-mingw-gcc) on this site. But the solution there don't worked.

The set of errors that I am getting, are happen when linking against the dynamic, not the static version, thus the reply on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13384510/glew-linker-errors-undefined-reference-to-glewbindvertexarray) question instead is likely wrong.

I did attempted the solutions there anyway, don't worked.

The only thing I don't tried yet is stuffing the glew.c files on the project and compiling with it, but I wanted a real solution, why glew is problematic to link like that? (there are lots of similar questions, not just here on SO but all over the internet)

Comment: There are a lot posts on the Internet about problem with linking with third party libraries, not just GLEW, because a lot people make the same mistakes. I have no idea what's causing your problem because the only information you've given about your actual problem  is a partial error message. Try creating a minimal complete and verifiable example that reproduces the problem and include in your question itself, along with the commands you used to build it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The project is not mine, I don't even know what glew do, how I am supposed to do that? I just want to compile a game so I can play it updated and fix some bugs on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are on Linux, since you have not mentioned what OS you are on. You can try this:

```
pkg-config --libs --static glew
```

Copy the libs it returns and paste after gcc/g++ command in the following format:

```
 g++ <input-file> -o <output-file> <output from pkg-config>
```

This is supposed to solve your problem.

Comment: you should really read the question, and tags. dlls (mentioned in the question) are windows only. the tags also have "windows" and "mingw-w64" in them, w64 even refers to "Windows 64bit" so even the amount of bits of my OS is known in the question.

Comment: **Please see** [ask] **and** [answer]